# Integrate Dropwizard and Apache Spark

Tags: logging, gradle, apache-spark, dependencies, dropwizard

I'm implementing an online classification service using Apache Spark. I have a problem when trying to submit the application to the a stand alone cluster with this script

```
 $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --class com.example.msclassification.MscApplication\
  --master spark://192.168.55.165:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --executor-memory 2G \
  --total-executor-cores 4 \
  ./build/libs/msclassification-0.0.1-all.jar -server configuration.yml
```

it give me an exception like this:

```
   16/03/01 11:25:45 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire the logger context
    at io.dropwizard.logging.LoggingUtil.getLoggerContext(LoggingUtil.java:46)
    at io.dropwizard.logging.BootstrapLogging.bootstrap(BootstrapLogging.java:45)
    at io.dropwizard.logging.BootstrapLogging.bootstrap(BootstrapLogging.java:34)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.<init>(Application.java:24)
    at com.example.msclassification.MscApplication.<init>(MscApplication.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:186)
    at com.example.msclassification.MscApplication.main(MscApplication.groovy:23)
    ... 6 more
```

When testing, there is a conflict for the logging and I have resolved that using the following gradle buildscript:

```
group 'com.example'
version '0.0.1'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
mainClassName = "com.example.msclassification.MscApplication"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile ('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11')
    compile ("io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:${project.properties.dropwizardVersion}")
    compile ("io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jdbi:${project.properties.dropwizardVersion}")
    compile ("org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:${project.properties.elasticsearchVersion}")
    compile 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.18'
    compile 'nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka:weka-dev:3.7.11'
    compile 'org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1'
    compile ('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4'
    compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.6.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }
    compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10:1.6.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }

//    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0'
}

buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.2'
    }
}


//State the main entry and merge service files
shadowJar{
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
    mergeServiceFiles()
    zip64 true
}

runShadow{
    args 'server', "${project.properties.dropwizardConfig}"
}
```

In this script, I have forced using the `jackson databind 2.4.4` and `log4j-over-slf4j` to revole package conflicting for Spark is using an old version of jackson and it use `SLF4J LOG4J-12` for log binding, whether Dropwizard is using `Logback` and there're no ways to exclude that or force it to use log4j without an error. Could you please suggest something? I would feel very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that something else is including log4j on your path and thus causing `getILoggerFactory` to return something other than a LoggingContext in [this code](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/logging/LoggingUtil.java#L41).

To find out what resource is pulling in log4j consider running:

```
gradle -q dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency log4j
```

**Spark actually pulls in log4j explicitly as a dependency (not just through slf4j) so that is likely the source of your issue.** Explicitly exclude log4j in your Spark dependencies and you should be good to go.